# NFS mounting options rsize and wsize can't be specified in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, nfs

The options `rsize` and `wsize` can not be specified on Centos7(3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64)

> cat /etc/fstab:
>
> 192.168.11.1:/linux_nfs_share /mnt/nfs01        nfs     intr,rw,bg,hard,vers=3,proto=tcp,timeo=600,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576
>
> mount:
>
> 192.168.11.1:/linux_nfs_share on /mnt/nfs01 type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=**65536**,wsize=**65536**,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys......)

On RHEL6 (2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64) it works...

> mount:
>
> 192.168.11.1:/linux_nfs_share on /mnt/FAS_NFS type nfs (rw,bg,hard,vers=3,proto=tcp,timeo=600,**rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576**....)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

[Known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1519701) in `nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.48.el7_4.2.x86_64` and possibly other versions.

In the current version for CentOS 7.x, `nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.61.el7.x86_64`, this seems to be fixed.